# Como checar se um arquivo é uma imagem?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, file-upload

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação usando ASP.NET MVC e AngularJS e preciso garantir que o upload de arquivo será somente arquivos de imagem, mesmo que alguém envie uma extensão de outro tipo de ".jpg" por exemplo.

Estou recebendo um *MultipartFileData* no back-end.

Já tentei checar o *contentType* do arquivo *header* mas, por exemplo,se eu mudar a extensão de um arquivo de texto para imagem, o *contentType* ainda mostrará que é "image/png".

Existe uma maneira mais fácil de assegurar que o usuário somente selecionará e enviará imagens verdadeiras? (jpeg, jpg, png,bmp, etc).

Comment: André, este é o [pt.so]. Clique em [edit] e traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Olá, você está perguntando no SO em português, tente mudar o idioma da sua pergunta. De qualquer forma, já tem uma resposta para isso no SO em inglês:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063900/determine-if-uploaded-file-is-image-any-format-on-mvc

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda pessoal , vou tentar replicar a solução apresentada.

Answer (score 4):

Tente abrir o *stream* do arquivo em um objeto `Bitmap`. Se funcionar a imagem é um conteúdo *raster* válido (png, jpg, jpeg, gif e outros).

```
try
{
   var bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(arquivoRecebido.InputStream);
}
catch 
{
    // Esse aquivo não é uma imagem.
}
```

Comment: _Approach_ bem javeiro, porém infalível e simplíssimo.

Comment: @LINQ programação orientada a *try/catch*. Uugh.